# (MacOS) Django can't find the MySQL driver ... but, why?

Tags: mysql, django

Here's the traceback:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mike/.virtualenvs/djangoprod/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/mike/.virtualenvs/djangoprod/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: '@rpath/libmysqlclient.21.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/Users/mike/.virtualenvs/djangoprod/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-310-darwin.so'
  Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib' (no such file)
```

And here's the problem:

```
$ locate libmysqlclient
[...]
/usr/local/mysql-8.0.31-macos12-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
```

So, the library *is there,* but Django isn't finding it.  So, before I "bang my head uselessly against this thing," especially given that it *used to work,* will someone out there kindly give me a nudge in the right direction? What am I missing here?

I particularly notice that the package is trying the path, `/usr/lib...` when that is not in fact the proper location *here.*

In particular: I see in the text a reference to `@rpath` which I am sure is the root cause of the problem – obviously, the value is wrong. (I notice that it *does* have the library-name right.)  I'm frankly not familiar with this `@rpath` thing, nor exactly what sets it.

Thank you kindly in advance ...

Comment: P.S.:  I also want to add to this that ... *"it used to work just fine."*  Until an unspecified amount of time ago, I had no issues whatsoever such as these.  I have, of course, already researched quite a few `sudo ln -s` "solutions," but I can't believe that they are the "real" right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to have asked this question so many times ...

It appears that System Integrity Protection (SIP) ***was*** the root cause of the problem.  Turning it off caused the library to be found, once it had been added with `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH ...etc...`

Instructions and explanation can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection

According to the Apple Developer website, this causes the value of `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to be denied to *child processes.*  And apparently, the Python interface for MySQL must use one somewhere.  *(How doing such an odd thing would benefit "system integrity" is quite beyond me, but Apple must have its reasons. ...)*

**FYI:** I also found out from Apple's `man dyld` page what `@RPATH` means and where its value comes from.